# Java: Round to arbitrary values

Tags: java, math, rounding

In Java, how do I round to an arbitrary value? Specifically, I want to round to .0025 steps, that is:

0.032611 -> 0.0325

0.034143 -> 0.0350

0.035233 -> 0.0350

0.037777 -> 0.0375

...

Any ideas or libs?

Answer (score 20):

```
y = Math.round(x / 0.0025) * 0.0025
```

Comment: I voted up, but I guess this formula doesn't handle the 2nd case, where the rouding is upwards and not downwards.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I've changed it to Math.round().

Comment: I'm worried about fp inaccuracy on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
double step = 0.0025;
double rounded = ((int)(unrounded / step + 0.5)) * step;
```

Comment: i believe in java it's getting to the same problem as it gets in C++: casting to int will truncate large double values into smaller ones. 1e300 for example will become something around 2e9. consider using ceil/floor to avoid the same mess as i did today when answering a similar round question :)